# SQL Server Pivot Attendance record according Time-In and Time-Out

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Does someone have an idea how can I come-up with the solutions of my requirements?
I have Attendance table with structure([ID],[DATE],[EMPID],[TIME]). See below:

```
ID  DATE        EMPID   TIME        REMARKS
1   20/09/2018  9001    7:30        This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9001
2   20/09/2018  9001    7:40        This will be the In_2 as it is the second TIME-IN for EMPID=9001
3   20/09/2018  9001    7:50        Not included
4   20/09/2018  9001    17:10       This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9001
5   20/09/2018  9001    17:50       This will be the Out_2 as it is the second TIME-OUT for EMPID=9001
6   20/09/2018  9001    18:00       Not included
7   20/09/2018  9002    7:20        This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9002
8   20/09/2018  9002    7:21        This will be the In_2 as it is the second TIME-IN for EMPID=9002
9   20/09/2018  9002    18:00       This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9002
10  20/09/2018  9003    7:00        This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9003
11  20/09/2018  9003    17:10       This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9003
11  20/09/2018  9003    17:12       This will be the Out_2 as it is the second TIME-OUT for EMPID=9003
11  20/09/2018  9003    17:15       Not included
```

And output will be the same as below:

```
DATE        EMPID   IN_1    IN_2    OUT_1   OUT_2
20/09/2018  9001    7:30    7:40    17:10   17:50
20/09/2018  9002    7:20    7:21    18:00   
20/09/2018  9003    7:20    17:10   17:12
```

Comment: is there another column that identify the record is a `IN` or `OUT` ?

Comment: @Squirrel , nothing in this table, it will only joined with the empworkshifts of which has link to employee id with [StartTime] and [EndTime]. So it is understood if the employee work shift is DS-Day Shift, [StartTime] = 8:00, [Endtime] = 17:00 and work shift is NS-Night Shift ,[StartTime]=20:00, [EndTime] = 5:00

Comment: In third result row might be 17:10 need under OUT_1 and 17:12 under OUT_2. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you don't have a column that can identify IN from OUT, i have arbitrary use 12:00 as the separator time.

```
; WITH
cte AS
(
    SELECT  *, TYPE = CASE WHEN TIME < '12:00' THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END
    FROM    your_table
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by EMPID, DATE, TYPE ORDER BY TIME)
    FROM    cte
)
SELECT DATE, EMPID,
       IN_1  = MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'IN'  AND rn = 1 THEN TIME END),
       IN_2  = MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'IN'  AND rn = 2 THEN TIME END),
       OUT_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'OUT' AND rn = 1 THEN TIME END),
       OUT_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'OUT' AND rn = 2 THEN TIME END)
FROM    cte2
GROUP BY DATE, EMPID
```

Comment: this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pivot

```
;WITH CTE(ID,[DATE], EMPID,[TIME], REMARKS)
AS
(
SELECT 1 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'7:30' ,'This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9001'  UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'7:40' ,'This will be the In_2 as it is the second TIME-IN for EMPID=9001'    UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'7:50' ,' Not included'                                                       UNION ALL
SELECT 4 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'17:10',' This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9001'  UNION ALL
SELECT 5 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'17:50',' This will be the Out_2 as it is the second TIME-OUT for EMPID=9001' UNION ALL
SELECT 6 ,'20/09/2018', 9001,'18:00',' Not included'                                                       UNION ALL
SELECT 7 ,'20/09/2018', 9002,'7:20' ,' This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9002' UNION ALL
SELECT 8 ,'20/09/2018', 9002,'7:21' ,' This will be the In_2 as it is the second TIME-IN for EMPID=9002'   UNION ALL
SELECT 9 ,'20/09/2018', 9002,'18:00',' This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9002'  UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'20/09/2018', 9003,'7:00' ,' This will be the In_1 as it is the first TIME-IN in for EMPID=9003' UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'20/09/2018', 9003,'17:10',' This will be the Out_1 as it is the first TIME-OUT for EMPID=9003'  UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'20/09/2018', 9003,'17:12',' This will be the Out_2 as it is the second TIME-OUT for EMPID=9003' UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'20/09/2018', 9003,'17:15',' Not included'
)
SELECT [DATE], EMPID,[In_1],[In_2],[Out_1],[Out_2] FROM
(
SELECT [DATE], EMPID,[TIME]
,MAX(CASE  WHEN  CHARINDEX('In_1',REMARKS)>0 THEN 'In_1' 
           WHEN  CHARINDEX('In_2',REMARKS)>0 THEN 'In_2'
           WHEN  CHARINDEX('Out_1',REMARKS)>0 THEN 'Out_1'
           WHEN  CHARINDEX('Out_2',REMARKS)>0 THEN 'Out_2'
    ELSE 'NA' END)  AS Details
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [DATE], EMPID,[TIME]
)dt
PIVOT
(
MAX([TIME]) FOR Details IN ([In_1],[In_2],[Out_1],[Out_2])
)pvt
```

Result

```
DATE        EMPID   In_1    In_2    Out_1   Out_2
-------------------------------------------------
20/09/2018  9001    7:30    7:40    17:10   17:50
20/09/2018  9002    7:20    7:21    18:00   NULL
20/09/2018  9003    7:00    NULL    17:10   17:12
```